# how to obtain a matirix with each element being a matrix of different sizes in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, matrix

I'm acquiring data sequences using Data Acquisition Toolbox using MATLAB. I've two matrices each of different sizes. I want these two different matrices to be elements of another bigger matrix. Is it possible to achieve this?

Answer (score 3):

### Cell Array

I'm not quite sure what you are trying to achieve.

From what I understand, you need a [cell array](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/cell.html).

Write

```
a{1} = my_first_matrix;
a{2} = my_second_matrix;
```

then `a` will be a cell array. You can retrieve your two matrices (of different sizes) using `a{1}` and `a{2}` respectively.

---

### Block diagonal matrix

My other understanding of your question is that you may want your two matrices to be blocks on the diagonal of a bigger matrix. Then you can use square brackets to concatenate different matrices and `zeros` to pad with zeros:

```
a = [M1 zeros(size(M1, 1), size(M2, 2)); zeros(size(M1, 2), size(M2, 1)) M2];
```